# How to use multiple mount point location in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

my mongodb one file system full. and added new file system . i want use both the file system in dbPath for storing data in mongodb .
How to use multiple mount point location in mongodb dbPath in mongod.conf file ?

Comment: OS version centos 7.0
mongo Version :  "4.4.17

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is only single dbPath setting that you can use in your mongod.conf file , but there is some options to fix your problem:

1. Use LVM for your dbPath ( you can extend the partition even online [adding](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-increase-the-size-of-a-linux-lvm-by-adding-a-new-disk#) more phisical volumes to your volume group and respective logical volume )
2. Switch to [sharded cluster](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/sharding/#sharding) and shard the database in more shards ( recommended when dbPath size is > 2TB in your single instance ).
3. With a [directoryPerDB](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage-options) configuration you can also mount or symlink subdirectories to different volumes in your filesystem ( this is not very recommended since it may complicate your snapshot backup strategy )